# Consulta de todas las ventas de un usuario con totales

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Estoy desarrollando con PHP-PDO con MySQL y tengo tres tablas:

- Usuario(Vendedor)
- Venta
- DetalleVenta

¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta en MySQL que me muestre **por usuario** el detalle de todas las ventas que realizó (producto, cantidad, precio, subtotal, *) más el total del precio del producto? Y volver al Nombre del usuario en una columna y no la fila.

Así es la relación entre las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola David, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). Sería ideal que editaras la pregunta y añadieras el código que hayas intentado así como una descripción de lo que no funcione o las dificultades/problemas que te estés encontrando. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto debería ser fácil, te recomiendo un curso de SQL y respondiendo a tu pregunta seria algo así:

```
select usus.Apellidos, group_concat(dets.IdProducto, '-', 
dets.DVCantidad, '-', dets.DVPrecio separator '\n') from usuarios usus, 
ventas vens, detalles dets where vens.IdEmpleado=usus.IdEmpleado and 
dets.IdVenta=vens.IdVenta group by usus.IdEmpleado
```

También puedes realizar sumas si gustas, o traer la información en formato JSON. Espero haberte dado un panorama de como trabajar.

Comment: Era justo lo que buscaba, me funciono a la perfección, muchas gracias, exitos.